# What library to connect so that you can use JSONLoader, OrbitControls, AnimationAction?

Tags: javascript, module, three.js

There are several different libraries, and not all of them have three functions available at once (JSONLoader, OrbitControls, AnimationAction). Which threejs to choose so that JSONLoader, OrbitControls, AnimationAction can be used? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!--&quot;-->
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Skelet Animation</title>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body translate="no" >
  <div id="webGL-container"></div>
  
//https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r98/three.min.js

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js'></script>
<script src="threejs/resources/threejs/r98/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script src="threejs/resources/threejs/r98/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
      <script id="rendered-js" >
      
$(function () {


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  canvas: document.querySelector('canvas'),
});

renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xCCCCCC));
renderer.setSize(window.innerHTML, window.innerHeight);




const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(7, 35, 15);

camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(18,0,0));

const orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
var ambientLight,grid, mesh, action = {}, mixer, fadeAction;
var bool1 = false;
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF);
directionalLight.position.set(-2,10,15);
directionalLight.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(10,0,0));
scene.add(directionalLight);




const loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var finger;
var material;


loader.load("./models/Marine.json", (geometry) =>
{

material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial ({
    color: 0xFE9A2E,
    wireframe: false,
    skinning: true
  });
  
  

  mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
  //*****************
  //animation
  //*****************
  action.run   = new THREE.AnimationAction( geometry.animations[ 0 ] );
  action.run.weight   = 1;
  mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );
  mixer.addAction( action.run );
  //*****************
  //end animation
  //*****************
  redraw();
});

function showWireframe( visibility ) {
    material.wireframe = visibility;
}


var redraw = function() {
  

  requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    renderer.render(scene,camera)
  })
};



function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
  if (needResize) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }
  return needResize;
}




function render(time) {
  if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
};
requestAnimationFrame(render);
});

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also attached file, with character animation. The animation is from Blender, so the movement may not display well.

https://e1.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZykbFZCyr8y4KHTxJ843vWw7CdCyghM3ek

Used for work: three.min.js r98 and OrbitControls of the same version.

The corresponding error in the console is: “Uncaught TypeError: THREE.AnimationAction is not a constructor”

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use React Three, React Three Fiber and React Three Drei. It provides custom hooks for almost every usecase, and you can still use native ThreeJs in it. It's much easier to create animations and trigger them.

Checkout the docs!
https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/getting-started/introduction